# Where to find nutrition information for general foods?

Tags: food, nutrition-information, diet-tools

Counting calories is one thing, but trying to keep track of things like fat, protein, fiber, and carbohydrates are just as important in a good overall exercise plan.  It's not that hard to find nutrition information on processed foods, but when you buy fresh produce and the like it's a lot harder to find the information.  ***NOTE***: This is about everyday food (fruits, vegetables, meats, etc.), not fast food.

Has anybody found a good resource for (a) finding out nutrition information of food that do not normally come in packaging with that information, and possibly (b) being able to track that information for diet purposes (or combining them for recipes to find overall information)?

I've looked at http://nutritiondata.self.com/ before, but I've found a number of great healthy recipes have ingredients that it doesn't have or are difficult to find.  Also trying to build out a recipe is quite time consuming if there's more than a few ingredients (especially if you have to go through the process of converting units to fit the site's need).

Comment: Perhaps this is a start: http://www.whfoods.com/foodstoc.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com/) has nutritional information for a wide variety of foods. Just type in the food and the amount, and it will tell you the carbs, protein, fat, calories, etc.

For example: [50 g apples](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50+g+apples):

[image: apples]

It even works for things like raw ingredients, so if you know how much flour, sugar, and butter you put in a recipe, you could tally up each of those quantities, to get the total nutritional info for that recipe. For example, [2 cups flour + 1 cup butter + 2/3 cup brown sugar](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+cups+flour+%2B+1+cup+butter+%2B+2/3+cup+brown+sugar).

Comment: Wow, finally a use case for Wolfram Alpha that is beyond the "gee, that was cool to try" factor!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to find nutritional info on fruits and veg. because they are not written on the side of the packet in the supermarket so it's something you will need to research for yourself.

About.com has the breakdown on many foods including fruit and veg. here are the links:

[Nutrition information for individual fruits](http://nutrition.about.com/od/nutritionalinfofruits/Nutrition_Information_for_Individual_Fruits.htm)

[Nutrition information for vegetables](http://nutrition.about.com/od/nutritionalinfoveggies/Nutrition_Information_for_Vegetables.htm)

For more detailed information including meats and recipes, check out this link:

http://caloriecount.about.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have used [DailyBurn](http://www.dailyburn.com) and [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/).  I currently use Myfitnesspal.  Here are the features I recall.

DailyBurn

- Create/find food
- Create your own recipe
- Get USDA information on raw foods
- Enter/track more vitamin and minerals on full web browser version

MyFitnessPal

- Create/find food
- Create your own recipe
- Create your own meal
- Find raw foods searching for "[FOOD] raw", example: carrot raw
- Verify nutrition information (accuracy)

Comment: Please note that the question is a two parter, and Agent_9191 wants to know where the data can also be tracked.  It seems DailyBurn would be a good fit, as it used the USDA database for raw foods and allows you to track them.  However, the USDA database is not 100% accurate on all foods, as I have seen in the past :(

Answer (score 2):

http://www.livestrong.com is the best of the others I've tried. It allows user data and has a decent user interface unlike the competition. It'd be nice if they could all get together and offer a single database instead of the 5-6 bad ones you get now.

Another place to try is mysupermarket, for example [an Apple](http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/tesco-price-comparison/Fruit/Tesco_Braeburn_Apples_Class_1_Loose_Approx_160g.html)

Answer (score 1):

I like the layout of http://nutritiondata.self.com/ quite well, but I agree that it's missing a lot of common ingredients to recipes. The most holistic list I've ever found is the one maintained by the [FDA](http://www.nal.usda.gov/fnic/foodcomp/search/). It doesn't have as nice an interface, but I've found it to be incredibly comprehensive.